# Is there a one-liner to get the first element of a split?

Tags: perl

Instead of writing:

```
@holder = split /\./,"hello.world"; 
print @holder[0];
```

is it possible to just do a one-liner to just get the first element of the split? Something like:

```
print (split /\./,"hello.world")[0]
```

I get the following error when I try the second example:

```
print (...) interpreted as function at test.pl line 3.
syntax error at test.pl line 3, near ")["
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should have tried your hunch. That’s how to do it.

```
my $first = (split /\./, "hello.world")[0];
```

You could use a list-context assignment that grabs the first field only.

```
my($first) = split /\./, "hello.world";
```

To print it, use

```
print +(split /\./, "hello.world")[0], "\n";
```

or

```
print ((split(/\./, "hello.world"))[0], "\n");
```

The plus sign is there because of a syntactic ambiguity. It signals that everything following are arguments to `print`. The [perlfunc documentation on `print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) explains.

> Be careful not to follow the print keyword with a left parenthesis unless you want the corresponding right parenthesis to terminate the arguments to the print; put parentheses around all arguments (or interpose a `+`, but that doesn't look as good).

In the case above, I find the case with `+` much easier to write and read. YMMV.

Comment: Ah, the + is what I was asking for. It also applies to not just print, but variable assignment as well. Thanks so much.

Comment: Interpose with + looks so nice and it has less typing than parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist on using `split` for this then you could potentially be splitting a long string into multiple fields, only to discard all but the first. The third parameter to `split` should be used to limit the number of fields into which to divide the string.

```
my $string = 'hello.world';

print((split(/\./, $string, 2))[0]);
```

But I believe a regular expression better describes what you want to do, and avoids this problem completely.

Either

```
my $string = 'hello.world';
my ($first) = $string =~ /([^.]+)/;
```

or

```
my $string = 'hello.world';
print $string =~ /([^.]+)/;
```

will extract the first string of non-dot characters for you.

Answer (score 3):

> I get the following error when I try the second example:
>          "syntax error at test.pl line 3, near ")["

No, if you have warnings enabled as you should, you get:

```
print (...) interpreted as function at test.pl line 3.
syntax error at test.pl line 3, near ")["
```

which should be a big clue as to your problem.

Comment: You're right! I scanned through the output too quickly and didn't notice the first line. I'll add that in.