# Perl: Indexing function returning array syntax

Tags: arrays, perl, syntax

I have a question about Perl more out of curiosity than necessity. I have seen there are many ways to do a lot of things in Perl, a lot of the time the syntax seems unintuitive to me (I've seen a few one liners doing som impressive stuff).

So.. I know the function `split` returns an array. My question is, how do I go about printing the first element of this array without saving it into a special variable? Something like `$(split(" ",$_))[0]` ... but one that works.

Comment: `substr()` doesn't return an array, it returns a string.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say that `split` returns an array?

Comment: Yes I meant `split`, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
print ((split(" ", $_))[0]);
```

You need one set of parentheses to allow you to apply array indexing to the result of a function. The outer parentheses are needed to get around special parsing of `print` arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You're 99% there

```
$ perl -de0

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   0
  DB<1> $a = "This is a test"

  DB<2> $b = (split(" ",$a))[0]

  DB<3> p $b
This
  DB<4> p "'$b'"
'This'
```

Comment: He said he wanted to print it without assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to print the first element of a whitespace separated list.  The `\s+` regex matches one or more whitespace characters to split on.

```
 echo "1 2 3 4" | perl -pe 'print +(split(/\s+/, $_))[0]'
```

Also, see this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799344/is-there-a-one-liner-to-get-the-first-element-of-a-split).