# Storing a token resulting from a split directly to a scalar variable

Tags: perl, split, token, scalar

Help greatly appreciated:

I would like to know the most efficient way to store a particular token from a split directly to a scalar variable.

Take the following code for example:

```
my @temp = split( '_', $someString );
my $scalar = $temp[$index];
```

Is there a way to consolidate this into one line?
I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
my $scalar = @{split( '_', $someString )}[$index]
```

Again, help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [So.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904990/how-to-get-just-one-scalar-from-perl-split-command) [Many.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154324/indexing-directly-into-returned-array-in-perl) [Duplicates.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799344/is-there-a-one-liner-to-get-the-first-element-of-a-split)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following to pull an element from a list:

```
my $scalar = (split '_', $someString)[$index];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the index ahead of time you can assign to a list, e.g for index=2:

```
my (undef, undef, $scalar) = split '_', $someString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution of `split` directly:

```
my $someString = 'asdf_asdf_asdfasd_f';
my $index = 0;

print ((split '_', $someString)[$index]);
# or for your $scalar
$scalar = (split '_', $someString)[$index];
```

Output:

```
asdf
```